# WPF displays image in designer but not in running win forms app

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I have a winforms application which inside use one window written in WPF. This window has such a XAML inside:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Warning.png" />
```

WPF designer shows it well but when I launch application it shows nothing. Properties of the file are 'Build Action' = 'Resource' and 'Copy to Output Directory' = 'Do not copy'

Is there a way to display this image without having to load it manually in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the setting for "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer" and "Build Action" to "Content". It should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work in my application but I quickly created a new one with just one form and one window and it seems to work